# Python Lambda missing dependencies when set up through Amplify

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I've been trying to configure an Amplify project with a Python based Lambda backend API.

I have followed the tutorials by creating an API through the AWS CLI and installing all the dependencies through pipenv.

When I `cd` into the function's directory, my Pipfile looks like this:

```
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
src = {editable = true, path = "./src"}
flask = "*"
flask-cors = "*"
aws-wsgi = "*"
boto3 = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

And when I run `amplify push` everything works and the Lambda Function gets created successfully.
Also, when I run the deploy pipeline from the Amplify Console, I see in the build logs that my virtual env is created and my dependencies are downloaded.

Something else that was done based on github issues (otherwise build would definitely fail) was adding the following to `amplify.yml`:

```
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - ln -fs /usr/local/bin/pip3.8 /usr/bin/pip3
        - ln -fs /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
        - pip3 install --user pipenv
        - amplifyPush --simple
```

Unfortunately, from the Lambda's logs (both `dev` and `prod`), I see that it fails importing every dependency that was installed through Pipenv. I added the following in `index.py`:

```
import os
os.system('pip list')
```

And saw that NONE of my dependencies were listed so I was wondering if the Lambda was running through the virtual env that was created, or was just using the default Python.

How can I make sure that my Lambda is running the virtualenv as defined in the `Pipfile`?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda functions do not run in a virtualenv.  Amplify [uses pipenv](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/9eb6a5ae6fa585df20dc24ac390de4d0626f6bee/packages/amplify-python-function-runtime-provider/src/util/buildUtils.ts#L8) to create a virtualenv and download the dependencies. Then Amplify [packages](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/9eb6a5ae6fa585df20dc24ac390de4d0626f6bee/packages/amplify-python-function-runtime-provider/src/util/packageUtils.ts#L15) those dependencies, along with the lambda code, into a zip file which it uploads to AWS Lambda.

Your problem is either that the dependencies are not packaged with your function or that they are packaged with a bad directory structure.  You can [download the function code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html) to see exactly how the packaging went.